# Postgres DB redundancy/HA server-side (no pgpool or similar)

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, redundancy, pgpool

I start off with my question: how can I setup redundancy with several DBs without having to install anything special on each of the clients?

I have seen that the usual way to do it is to install something like `pgpool` on each client which can handle whether to write to the master or to pick a slave for the read. I would like to find a way to move the responsibility to the server, either by having a very small machine with just that dedicated function (effectively acting as Load Balancer) or something that can be setup on the DBs.

So the clients will only try to connect to `http://IP_BALANCER` and that machine will be able to revert all the operations accordingly, exactly as pgpool would do. Is that possible? If so, is that a good way to do it?

I am asking this question because the 'clients' would be a set of very light pods on a Kubernetes cluster. I managed to make the pods very minimal (they run with only compiled machine code) and I wouldn't want to have to add pgpool on top of them, since I would have to start adding an actual OS to be able to achieve that.

Comment: pgpool is **not** installed on the client side. The clients _connect to_ pgpool as if it was a Postgres server. You **are** looking for pgpool or pgbouncer

Comment: What I call clients is my backend containers which are connecting to the DBs.

Comment: Well with pgpool or pgbouncer they simply connect to a new/different server. That's all. There is nothing you need to "install" there. Just point them to the load balancer.

Comment: Basically, can I install pgpool on a dedicated server, tell my 'dumb' containers to connect there, and pgpool will do the job of balancing and accessing the master/slaves correctly?

Comment: Correct. The clients will think they connect to a Postgres server